How to speed up the performance of multiple update queries in SQL Server
Are there specific strategies or best practices that can be applied to expedite update operations in SQL Server, particularly when dealing with large datasets or complex update conditions?
I have utilized SqlBulkCopy to increase the speed of multiple insert queries. Now, I am trying to enhance the execution speed of multiple update queries. I've explored the MERGE statement as an option, but I'm uncertain about its comparative speed compared to conventional update queries.
Result using normal update query:
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 24 ms.
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 15 ms.
(101 row(s) affected)

Result using MERGE update query:
SQL Server Execution Times:
CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 62 ms.
(101 row(s) affected)


if you have a LOT of single row updates, it usually better to put the data into a staging table using bulk and do one single update.

Please provide your merge statement and table schema(s), including any supporting indexes. Also use Paste-the-Plan to provide the execution plan.

Things I look at for optimal MERGE operation are: (1) Ensure that you have matching data types between your source and target tables. (2) Define appropriate indexes to support the merge-condition combined with any WHEN clause conditions. (3) If you are refreshing just a slice of your target data, and have an additional filter condition like AND TGT.Date = @Date on the DELETE, consider moving that condition to the merge target definition to reduce the amount of data processed through the initial matching process - MERGE ... INTO (SELECT * FROM Data D WHERE D.Date = @Date) AS TGT.

Is 39 milliseconds really an area you need to optimize?

One thing's for sure, don't use merge when you only update rows, the only time it will be faster is when you hit some merge bug

SQL Server performance usually comes down to indexing. In your case, you may have two places where indexing can help or hurt you:

Are you searching for the records to update based on columns that are part of an index? If not you can try wither creating a temporary index (making sure to delete it when you're done or add a permanent index on those columns.  If the values you're searching for are part of a clustered index, then it will be even faster, but you can have only one clustered index per table, since that index determines the physical order of records.

Are you updating columns that are part of other indexes? That will slow things down slightly since those indexes have to be updated.


Other than that, you'll have to get a DBA to look at query plans and other statistics to see if there's anything that can be optimized. It's generally not enough to look at the SQL alone.
As far as UPDATE vs MERGE, if you are ONLY updating records, then a MERGE will likely not perform faster than a straight UPDATE. In fact, it might perform SLOWER as it will see which records need to be INSERTed which would be a waste of time if you are only updating records.
